# Trapping Tab and Shift tab inside a modal

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to trap tab and shift+tab focus to within a dialog/modal. I currently have the following:

```
  var firstAnchor = document.getElementById("first"),
      lastAnchor = document.getElementById("last");

  function keydownHandler(f) {
    var evt = f || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    if(keyCode === 9) { // TAB pressed
      if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
      else evt.returnValue = false;
      firstAnchor.focus();
    }
  }

  if(lastAnchor.addEventListener) lastAnchor.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler, false);
  else if(lastAnchor.attachEvent) lastAnchor.attachEvent('onkeydown', keydownHandler);
```

and it works for tab but what would be needed to also trap shift+tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the addition of a function to bind to the first element of your group:

```
var firstAnchor = document.getElementById("first"),
      lastAnchor = document.getElementById("last");

  function keydownHandler(f) {
    var evt = f || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    if(keyCode === 9) { // TAB pressed
      if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
      else evt.returnValue = false;
      firstAnchor.focus();
    }
  }

  function keydownHandlerFirst(f) {
    var evt = f || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    if(keyCode === 9 && evt.shiftKey) { // TAB+SHIFT pressed
      if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
      else evt.returnValue = false;
      lastAnchor.focus();
    }
  }

  if(lastAnchor.addEventListener) lastAnchor.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler, false);
  else if(lastAnchor.attachEvent) lastAnchor.attachEvent('onkeydown', keydownHandler);
  if(firstAnchor.addEventListener) firstAnchor.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandlerLast, false);
  else if(firstAnchor.attachEvent) firstAnchor.attachEvent('onkeydown', keydownHandlerLast);
```

And I've been reminded why I use frameworks... Can you believe we used to write all our javascript like this?!